# Como puedo mostrar la info de una fk con un select?

Tags: mysql, mysqli, mysql-workbench

les explico, tengo una tabla llamada empleado

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS empleado(
    numEmpleado int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    nombre VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    sueldo bigint NOT NULL,
    fContratacion DATE NOT NULL,
    numSucursal int,
    jefe int NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fkjefe
    FOREIGN KEY (jefe) REFERENCES empleado(numEmpleado),
    CONSTRAINT fksucursal
    FOREIGN KEY (numSucursal) REFERENCES sucursal(numSucursal)
);
```

Tengo que hacer un select mostrando el nombre, el sueldo, la fecha de contratacion y el nombre del jefe.

Mi problema es que cuando muestro el jefe me aparece su id (numEmpleado)

Como puedo mostrar el nombre del jefe?

Tengo este select

```
SELECT nombre, sueldo, fContratacion, jefe FROM empleado;
```

pero en vez de la id del jefe debo mostrar su nombre.

Vi que puedo crear una vista, o un select con join, pero no me resulta :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que hacer un `JOIN` con la misma tabla relacionando jefe con el numEmpledo del jefe.

```
SELECT e.nombre, e.sueldo, e.fContratacion, e.jefe, e2.nombre as nombre_jefe FROM empleado e
JOIN empleado e2 ON e2.numEmpleado  = e.jefe;
```

El nombre viene en el campo `nombre_jefe`.

Comment: Hey muchísimas gracias, me funciono, y empiezo a comprender mejor sobre esas queries.

Comment: De nada, un placer.